# Malicious request in log

Tags: php

I am receiving malicious request therefore i seek your help i log page urls visited and some of them are like `http://example.com/?a=fetch&content=<php>die(@md5(HelloThinkCMF))</php>` and some are like `http://example.com/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm` and one more like `http://example.com/index.php?s=/Index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&var` what are these user trying to do and how should I improve the security and take precaution

Comment: @Justinas yeah i know but your comment does not solve my doubt

Comment: This is more a question about system administration than programming.

Comment: @NigelRen some php commands were mentioned thats why I ask in php community

Comment: @aryanagarwal There is no PHP commands, there is only URL variables with strings. If you directly execute them, then it's problem, otherwise it's safe

Comment: @Justinas so the hacker assumes i use `a` and `content` as get parameters ?

Comment: @aryanagarwal that, _and_ you put them _as is_ into something like `eval`. **Or** he is sending it to it's own already injected script that resits somewhere in your server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the users are trying to use URL injection to attack your website. They are adding malicious code to urls and sending them to the web server. If this code is run by the Php process, then it can cause damage to databases or the file system.

I faced a similar problem. I was able to fix the problem by installing Fail2Ban and ModSecurity. ModSecurity is an open source Web Application Firewall. It allows blocking malicious requests using predefined rules. Fail2Ban is a server intrusion prevention tool that checks for certain text patterns in log files using regular expressions. It automatically adds rules to the system's firewall, banning the user.

See these blog posts on how to install [Fail2ban](https://pakjiddat.netlify.app/posts/preventing-ssh-and-sql-injection-attacks-using-fail2ban) and [Modsecurity](https://pakjiddat.netlify.app/posts/integrating-modsecurity-with-nginx-on-debian-9).

Comment: Thanks a lot I will have a look at them for now do I need to pull down my website ?

Comment: Well I think you should put the website in maintenance mode. Maybe show a message like "This website is currently down for maintenance. We will be back up shortly".